# Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. Suppose $Y\subseteq X$ and $X$ is countable. Prove that $Y$ is countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. Suppose $Y\subseteq X$ and $X$ is countable. Prove that $Y$ is countable.

Since $X$ is countable, $\exists f:\mathbb{N} \to X$ and $f$ is bijection.

Consider $g: \mathbb{N} \to X$, and because $Y \subseteq X \implies g \mid_y :\mathbb{N} \to X,y \in Y$

Is this making sense as a beginning of the proof? I got a little confused about what I am trying to do.

Comment: According to the definition in the second line of your question, countable sets are infinite. However, when $Y \subseteq X$, $Y$ can be finite, therefore it may not be countable.

Comment: To explain thePortakal's comment.  If f is a bijection then X is infinite.  If X is finite countable, then f is not a bijection.  No bijection exists.  But there does exist a surjection.  You may or may not need to prove if a surjection exists a cardinality is equal or less.  But yes, you are definitely on a good track.

Answer (score 5):

There exist $f\colon X \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ an injection. Then $f|_{Y}\colon Y \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is also an injection. Then $Y$ is countable.

Answer (score 0):

The proof here depends on how one defines **countable**. For instance, one might strictly define

> A set $A$ is said to be *countable* if there exists a bijective correspondence $A \text{ ~ } \mathbb{N}$.

and use the term *at most countable* in the general case where $A$ is either finite (i.e., a bijection exists between $A$ and $J_n \subset \mathbb{N}$, any set of $n$ positive integers) or countable. If however, you define "countable" in the same way as "at most countable," then for finite $Y$ with $|Y| = n$ we may write

\begin{align}f(Y) \subseteq f(X) = \mathbb{N} \quad \implies \quad f(Y) = J_n
\end{align}

In other words, we restrict the domain of $f$ to the elements of $Y$. Otherwise, if both $X$ and $Y$ are infinite they must be equivalent to $\mathbb{N}$ itself, thus $Y$ is countably infinite.